# Enabling Task Manager Which Is Disabled By Virus?

Tags: windows-xp

I want to enable task manager is disabled by the virus when I enable this it is automatically disable by the virus again I want permanent solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only permanent solution is to eradicate the virus.

[Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) is excellent for removing viruses.

You can also use an 
antivirus online scan such as [ESET Online Scanner](http://www.eset.com/online-scanner), [Trend Micro House Call](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/) and [Kaspersky Labs Free Virus Scan](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner). Please note that they might require you to use Internet Explorer as your browser as an administrator, and that each scan may take several hours.

Comment: Can't get more permanent than that.

Answer (score 1):

I too would recommend use of an [anti-virus](http://free-av.com/) as a permanent solution. Though you can avoid such future problems by limiting Write Permissions to the registry key :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Note : Delete the `DisableTaskMgr` value before limiting permissions.